# How to make whole POD object read and update operations lockfree?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, .net-4.5, versioning

Say we have a POD type:

```
    private class Messages {
        public byte[] last;
        public byte[] next;
    }
```

and its instance `messages`.

When a user (caller) requests instance we want to give him deep copy of messages object (that can be not the latest). When a user sets his own version we want to provide it to others as sun as possible yet not interrupting read requests (older version should be removed, not interrupting reads as soon as possible).

How to do such object versioning using System.Collections.Concurrent?

What have I tried:

```
    internal class CuncurrentMessagesHelper {
        private readonly ConcurrentStack<Messages> _stack = new ConcurrentStack<Messages>();
        public CuncurrentMessagesHelper() {
        }

        public void SetLatest(Messages m) {
            var length = _stack.Count;
            _stack.Push(m);
            var range = new Messages[length];
            _stack.TryPopRange(range, 0, length);
        }

        public bool ReadLatest(out Messages result) {
            return _stack.TryPeek(out result);
        }
    }
```

Yet such helper approach seems as ugly hack.

1. because even we know result is garanteed we use try and return bool instead of object;
2. it TryPopRange makes us create addintional array with size of all previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't POD. It's a POCO. I suggest you read up on the difference between .NET's value types and reference types, since their semantics are crucial while writing safe concurrent code.

Since C# references are guaranteed to be atomic, the solution is simple (and doesn't require any special concurrent containers).

Assuming your `Messages` object is immutable once passed in:

```
internal class ConcurrentMessagesHelper {
    private volatile Messages _current;

    public void SetLatest(Messages m) {
        _current = m;
    }

    public Messages ReadLatest() {
        return _current;
    }
}
```

Note that it's the reference to the object that's being copied here (atomically), and not the object's `byte[]` fields. `volatile` is required since the reference is accessed by multiple threads (it ensures correct behaviour, in particular with regards to memory ordering and limiting the optimizations the JIT can perform to only thread-safe ones).

If the `Messages` object passed to `SetLatest` can change while it's the latest, then all you have to do is make a copy first. `SetLatest` becomes:

```
public void SetLatest(Messages m) {
    _current = DeepClone(m);
}
```

If readers are allowed to change the `Messages` object returned, then you have to copy it before letting them have it too. `ReadLatest` becomes:

```
public Messages ReadLatest() {
    return DeepClone(_current);
}
```

Note that if the values contained in the `byte[]` fields of `Messages` are immutable during each message's lifetime, all you need is a shallow copy, not a deep one.

---

You can make the interface even nicer by wrapping it in a simple property:

```
internal class ConcurrentMessagesHelper {
    private volatile Messages _current;
    public Messages Current {
        get { return DeepClone(_current); }
        set { _current = DeepClone(value); }
    }

    private static Messages DeepClone(Messages m)
    {
        if (m == null)
            return null;
        return new Messages {
            last = m.last == null ? null : (byte[])m.last.Clone(),
            next = m.next == null ? null : (byte[])m.next.Clone()
        };
    }
 }
```

---

If you *actually* did have a POD type (e.g. `struct Messages`), then I suggest the simplest solution would be to wrap it in a class so you can have an atomic reference to a copy of it, which would allow you to use the solution above. `StrongBox<T>` comes to mind.

The code in such a case becomes even simpler, because no explicit copying is required:

```
private struct Messages {
    public byte[] last;
    public byte[] next;
}

internal class ConcurrentMessagesHelper {
    private volatile StrongBox<Messages> _current;
    public Messages Current {
        get { return _current.Value; }
        set { _current = new StrongBox<Messages>(value); }
    }
}
```

If the byte arrays in `Messages` can change during the object's lifetime, then we still need the deep cloning, though:

```
internal class ConcurrentMessagesHelper {
    private volatile StrongBox<Messages> _current;
    public Messages Current {
        get { return DeepClone(_current.Value); }
        set { _current = new StrongBox<Messages>(DeepClone(value)); }
    }

    private static Messages DeepClone(Messages m)
    {
        return new Messages {
            last = m.last == null ? null : (byte[])m.last.Clone(),
            next = m.next == null ? null : (byte[])m.next.Clone()
        };
    }
}
```